# Indexing neigboring values without loop

Tags: r, loops

I like to average out values from a data.frame that are smaller than their neighbors. This is the example:

```
 df <- data.frame(V1 = c(1:10), V2 = c(0.5, 1, 2, 6, 7, 6.5, 8, 8.2, 8.1, 8.5))

 for (i in 2:(nrow(df)-1)) {
    df[i,2] <- ifelse( 
      df[i,2] < df[i+1,2] & df[i,2] < df[i-1,2], 
      mean(c(df[i+1,2], df[i-1,2])), 
      df[i,2]
    )
 }
```

Is there a better way to omit the for-loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this vectorized:

```
inds <- which(with(df, V2<c(NA,head(V2,-1)) & V2<c(tail(V2,-1),NA)))
#[1] 6 9

df$V2[inds] <- (df$V2[inds-1]+df$V2[inds+1])/2

   # V1   V2
# 1   1 0.50
# 2   2 1.00
# 3   3 2.00
# 4   4 6.00
# 5   5 7.00
# 6   6 7.50
# 7   7 8.00
# 8   8 8.20
# 9   9 8.35
# 10 10 8.50
```

Answer (score 0):

We can try

```
 i1 <- c(FALSE, (df$V2[-nrow(df)] - df$V2[-1])>0 & (df$V2[-1] - df$V2[-nrow(df)]) < 0)

df$V2[i1] <- sapply(which(i1), function(i) mean(df$V2[c(i-1,i+1)]))
df$V2
#[1] 0.50 1.00 2.00 6.00 7.00 7.50 8.00 8.20 8.35 8.50
```

Or

```
i2 <- which(i1)
df$V2[i2] <- (df$V2[i2-1] + df$V2[i2+1])/2
```

Or using `na.approx`

```
library(zoo)
df$V2 <- na.approx(df$V2*NA^(i1))
```

Comment: `i1 <- c(FALSE, diff(df$V2)< 0)` wouldn't this select all values less than the previous value? Rather than only those less than both the one before and the one after?